How to reference parent Product from OpportunityLineItem?
I need to create formula that references Product2 field from child Opportunity Line Item product. When I try next formula:
Product2.CustomField__c or Product2Id.CustomField__c

I get error Error:

Field Product2 does not exist. Check spelling.

Is there any way to reference Product field from OpportunityLineItem in formula ?

You cannot directly reference fields from the Product2 object in a formula field on the OpportunityLineItem object.
As per documentation,

The ID of the related Product2 record. This is a read-only field
available in API version 30.0 and later. Use the PricebookEntryId
field instead, specifying the ID of the PricebookEntry record.

So you can use pricebookentryid field to get the product field.
PricebookEntry.Product2.CustomField__c

